# How to use Laravel elequent model to get data with mutiple where condition

Tags: laravel-5.1, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and currently working on Laravel 5.1. I am trying to authenticate user by its email and password. To get this, I am using the below code to find the user:

First Method: Using Elequent Model

```
$result = user_model::where('email', $data['email'])->where('password', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($data['password']))->first();
```

Second Method: Using with() Method:

```
$result = user_model::where('email', $data['email'])
        ->where(function($q) use($data) {
            $q->where('password', '=', Hash::make($data['password']));
        })->first();
```

Third Method: Using query Builder:

```
$result = DB::table('users')->where('email', $data['email'])->where('password', Hash::make($data['password']))->get();
```

Each of the above method is returning null even the the user is exist into database.

If I use single where condition either for email or password then First method returns user object with data.

Can anyone help me for How can i get the result of query having multiple where conditions.

Comment: Laravel has a built-in auth, why are you doing this?

Comment: Yes I know Laravel has. But it is not upto user authentication. If I want to get data from other table with multiple condition then what will I do in that case?

Comment: Your where clauses are correct, the problem is that `Hash::make()` won't get you the same password hash that is stored in the DB, because of the unique salt. If you want to authenticate like this just get the user by email and run `Hash::check()` on the password and the hash.

Comment: Oh..Thanks for Reply